# Creating a heatmap using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to create a heatmap to display the data I have. The data consists of 3 columns with 100 rows. I used the following code to create the heatmap using ggplot package in R.

```
x=c("x1","x2","x3")
y=paste0("var",seq(1,100))
datax=expand.grid(x,y)
datax$z=runif(300,0,5)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(datax, aes(Var1, Var2, fill= z)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

I got an output as follows:
[image]

I want to make this graph prettier. i.e, here the each cells have a rectangle shapes. How to make it to appear as squares? Also is there way to remove the row names and put the column heading to the top of the plot?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [correlation heatmap using heatmaply R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955380/correlation-heatmap-using-heatmaply-r)

Comment: @Galen I am afraid it is not. I just want to create a heatmap for raw data. Not for the correlations

Answer (score 1):

The reason why they are rectangular is because there are many values on the y axis and only a few on the x axis. If you want them to be square you need to explicitly save the plot with a certain size.

Run this right after the `ggplot` command (no `+`) and play around with `width` and `height`. By default it will save the last plot displayed.

```
ggsave("filename.pdf", device = "pdf", width = <w>, height = <h>)
```

To get the x labels on top, use `+ scale_x_discrete(position="top")`. To remove the y axis variables altogether, use `+ theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())` (both after the ggplot call)

Other ideas:

- if you need more space take off the x and y labels with `+ xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)` after `geom_tile()`
- since this will likely be a tall, skinny graph, depending if you have another variable `var3` that can be used to subset the y axis you can use `facet_wrap(~var3)` to break the giant heatmap into smaller, more square-ish heatmaps